# Use functions from a different program

Tags: c, merge, linker, include, wireshark

I'm trying to make Wireshark call a functions from a different program. These 2 programs are independent from each other. Is there any way of linking these 2 programs and making Wireshark have the ability of calling a function from inside the second program?

I was thinking of adding the `#include` to the top of the code of the file which has the required functions. Would this be possible?  (I'll be trying it in a while since VS2013 is currently installing.)

Is there any other way of making this possible?

Comment: Is this part of a custom dissector?

Comment: @dbush The dissector is a custom dissector. But the new program is completely outside Wireshark. It's Allegro 5. I'm trying to use the graphing capabilities of Allegro 5 into Wireshark. This is technically what I'm trying to do: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838716/allegro-5-and-wireshark)

Answer (score 0):

There usually isn't a way for `programA` to call a function found in a separate executable `programB`.  You have a variety of options — the main ones are:

The normal method is to make the function available in a shared library (DLL), and for both programs to use the DLL to call the function.  The DLL might be linked at compile time or loaded at runtime.  A similar technique puts the function in a static library that is linked with the executables.

The less common method is to create an RPC (remote procedure call) interface to the function and have both programs (or, at least, `programA`) use the RPC interface.  There are many options for which RPC system to use.

You can also think of more esoteric techniques, such as exposing the function as a web service.